# Data Driven Pages Export Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, data-driven-pages

I have created mapbooks using DDP and am running into an exporting issue. I have 40 mapbooks of 40 different cities based on a my layer file called "Custom Grid".  When I go to export it gives me the option to either export all of the mapbooks together as one single PDF, or every page of each mapbook as an individual pdf.

There is a field in my layer file called "City_ID" in which I wish to append each mapbook page by.

I was wondering if there was a way to export an individual PDF for each mapbook (each city) without having to manually select each city (select by location or attributed) and then export one by one. Is there a simple arcpy script for this?

Comment: In the Export Map dialog box's Pages tab, did you try using the Export Pages As Multiple PDF Files Page Names and then click on the All radio button?  This assumes in the DDP Set up you've set the Name field to your City_ID.

Comment: Actually, when I do that, it's exporting them by CITY ID, but then there is only one page in each Mapbook (it's overwriting the previous page with the same CITY ID) instead of having every grid (each Mapbook page)

Comment: I know it sounds crazy but you might check the settings again because ArcMap changed a default setting on me last week and I got a single pdf with all the pages, all having the same bookmark name.  In the Export Map dialog box the Export Pages As drop down defaulted to single pdf file, not Multiple PDF Files (page names) which is what was needed.  Second, that dialog box also defaults to Current Page, not All, unless you have a selection on your index layer.  Third, in the Data Driven Pages Setup Definition, the Name field must be set to City_ID for your case.

Comment: I agree with @johns - this should already be out-of-the-box functionality - would you be able to **edit** your question to list your precise steps with some screenshots of any settings you make, please?